# Shortcut to open terminal in the currently open directory on GUI

Tags: command-line

Are there any shortcuts to launch a terminal in the currently active directory in the GUI? For example say I am browsing the directory `cd ~/Projects/A/B/C/D/ED` on GUI. I wish to open a terminal with the current directory active at that location without opening a terminal and `cd` ing into it? Are there any shortcuts or methods to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can start the terminal by right-clicking at empty space in file manager and selecting the option there.

Comment: Right clicking doesnt give an option to open a terminal

Comment: Ok. What is your desktop environment? In Xfce there is such option.

Comment: Mine is unity .

Comment: Probably it's the file manager's fault. Try installing and using "Thunar" file manager.